# ASUS Q550LF and 64GB SDXC card

Tags: drivers, usb, sd-card

I recently bought an ASUS Q550LF laptop.  Core i7, nVidia GF745M, three USB 3.0 ports.

I'm trying to get a 64GB SDXC card to mount, and cannot seem to.  I installed fuse-exfat and exfat-utils; this solution worked perfectly on my old ASUS UL50VT.  However, no go on the new box.

I was able to capture a screenshot with my phone of the following error after plugging in a USB reader caused my system to crash enough to need a reboot:

```
xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0 setup ERROR: setup context command for slot 1.
usb 1-4: hub failed to enable device, error -22
```

this error repeated exactly the same twice for slot 1, twice for slot 28, twice for slot 4, twice for slot 28, then slot 4, then slot 1.

So I am guessing there's a problem with the way my USB drivers are set up on this machine.  It's a stock install, I haven't done anything to change the USB and the SDXC card function has never worked.

However when I use the same reader with a 16GB card, it works just fine and is really fast in read and write, so  I don't think my reader is bad.

I'm unsure where to go next.

Comment: This is not actually an issue with the USB subsystem, but an issue with the card reader. Can you please provide the output of `lsusb` and edit your question to include it?